# How to override default python functions like round()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I Want to override default round() function of python because I have to convert the result of round() function into integer. By default round() returns value in float.
The code given below is returning error message.

**RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.**

```
def round(number):
     if type(number) is float: return int(round(number))
     return None
```

Comment: Why not just define a new function with a separate name?

Comment: You have infinite recursion, because you are calling the same round() function you declared inside your if condition - infinitely!

Comment: He's calling round(number) before int() ... the `number` will always be the original param passed

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.

Comment: why are you returning None and why not just call `int(round(numer))`, why would you be passing something other than a number to a round function?

Comment: Padaric Cunningham I will pass this function in template as context that's why I am  returning none if the argument passed in the function is not float.

Comment: What happens if you pass an int?

Comment: It will return None on arguments which are other than float type

Comment: Are you trying to pass back `None` as an error code (a la `null`)? Python is not C; just raise an error. In any event, you should learn and use the concept of duck typing. If some other float type comes along (e.g. from `decimal`, Numpy, etc.) your function will choke and die.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that after you have overwritten the built-in `round()` method, when you call `round()` inside your own `round()` , you are recursively calling your own function, not the built-in `round` function.

For Python 3.x, you can use [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module to access the `round()` built-in function -

```
import builtins
def round(number):
    if type(number) is float: return int(builtins.round(number))
    return None
```

For Python 2.x , it would be [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) module -

```
import __builtin__
def round(number):
    if type(number) is float: return int(__builtin__.round(number))
    return None
```

Though I would really suggest not doing this, rather use a new name for your round function, maybe something like `round_int` or so.

Please note, another thing is that your code would return the rounded number for `float` type, for all other types, it would return `None` , I am not sure if this is intentional or not, but I am guessing you would want to return back the `number` for other types (atleast `int`?) .

Comment: It is intentional to accept only float numbers. I want to convert decimals into integer by rounding off the number.

Comment: Thanks @anand s kumar.

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out, round refers to your function not to the builtin function as you have shadowed the function and as python looks in the *local, enclosing, global scope*  and finally *builtins* in that order it see round refers to your function so your function essentially keeps calling itself until you hit a recursion limit.

I would avoid shadowing the round function at all but a much simpler approach would be a `try/except` adding .5 to the number passed in and catching a TypeError:

```
def round(number):
    try:
        return int(number + .5)
    except TypeError:
        return None
```

If you were going to check types, you should use `issinstance`, you can combine it with `numbers.Number` to check for any numeric type:

```
from numbers import Number
def round(number):
    if isinstance(number, Number):
        return int(number+.5)
    return None
```

If you just wanted to check for a float type:

```
def round(number):
    if isinstance(number, float):
        return int(number+.5)
    return None
```

Comment: *`I would avoid shadowing`* - as I do. Isn't it more consistent then to use another name for the examples?

Comment: @Wolf, I said *I would avoid shadowing the round function at all but ...*, as in but if you are going to. The code provided lets the OP shadow round without the need to use builtins at all.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you might want to apply `round` to a specific class that does not support it by default.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def __round__(self, precision):
        if precision <= 0:
            self.x = int(self.x)
            self.y = int(self.y)
        else:
            self.x = round(self.x, precision)
            self.y = round(self.y, precision)
        # do whatever
        return self
```

When defined in a class, the `__round__` method will overload the builtin `round`.

Tested on Python 3.10.